# Rails Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Hello everyone I have this code that I have been working on for my website. I am trying to implement a carousel feature where one picture slides on after the other. The problem I am having is that the pictures will not slide. Here is what my code looks like in the index page of my welcome controller:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <body>


<div id = "myCarousel" class = "carousel slide" data-interval="1000" data-ride="carousel" >               
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ol>

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class = "item-active">
                    <%= image_tag("slide2.jpg", class: "img-responsive") %> 
                    </div>
                    <div class = "item">
                    <%= image_tag("slide1.jpg", class: "img-responsive") %> 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class = "icon-prev"></span>
                </a>

                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class = "icon-next"></span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>


        </body>
</html>
```

welcome.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
  });
});
```

Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this code below to your `application.js` file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
  });
});
```

Or you can simply pass options to your data attributes:

```
<div id = "myCarousel" class = "carousel slide" data-interval="1000" data-ride="carousel" >
```

reference:
 https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#via-javascript

I hope it helps!

**UPDATE**

I think you have some issues with js path. Are you sure about js path for bootstrap file?

If you put this code in `<head>` tag it will work for sure:

```
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: This is not working for me when I add the code for application.js. I also tried the other solution and that too did not work

Comment: So now when I click the arrows it shows two images on one page :(

Comment: Now you need to play with css :-)

Answer (score 0):

It might not be working because it is being called before jQuery loads.  I would put the code in a helper js file and include that file in your application.js

That should ensure that jQuery is loaded before your script is.

application.js
//= require helper_file

Comment: So would I do this code in lets say a welcome.js.coffee script file and call that file within my application.js file, or create an actual helper file

Comment: You can add it to the welcome file.  I just suggested a helper.js if you didn't have a js file you where including already.

Comment: I now have edited my post to show the changes I made. I have added the appropriate javascript to the welcome file but still no luck. Each time I try and click the left and right arrows to go to the next page nothing happens and it shows that the button was clicked in the url by showing #myCarousel

Comment: Can you post the cotents of your application.js file.  I'm wondering if the bootstrap js is being included.  You should have both of these in there.                                                                          //= require jquery
//= require bootstrap